# Unity Interception From Base Class

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity-container, aop, policy-injection

I want to declare interception to Unity for a particular base type, and have that interception be honored for all derived types automatically.

I see two different SO posts that are the same topic, but neither has the answer I'm looking for:

- [Microsoft Unity Base Class Interception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16130106/microsoft-unity-base-class-interception)
  This one tells me what I already know; it is still not enough information.
- [Unity Interception in Derived Classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273886/unity-interception-in-derived-class)
  This one is very detailed, but pertains to Unity configuration instead of the imperative form I am using.

So I'd like to show the code I have, and see if I can get an answer specific to my scenario.

I have these classes:

```
public abstract class RootController
{
    [Report]
    public abstract void Action();
}

public class MyController
{
    public void Action()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("hey");
    }
}
```

The [Report] annotation is my own custom attribute - it indicates AOP logging should be applied to the method.  I arrange for it to be used with policy-based interception as follows:

```
container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();

container.RegisterInstance<InjectionPolicy>(typeof(ReportAttributePolicy).AssemblyQualifiedName, new ReportAttributePolicy());

container.RegisterType<RootController>(
   new Interceptor<VirtualMethodInterceptor>(),
   new InterceptionBehavior<PolicyInjectionBehavior>()
);
```

The `ReportAttributePolicy` is my custom version of `AttributeDrivenPolicy`.  See my [Unity Interception](http://www.ariasamp.net/2013/09/fixing-attribute-interception-dependencies-in-unity/) blog post for details.

Obviously the scenario I'm trying to make work is this:

```
        var yup = container.Resolve<MyController>();
```

Even though the requested type merely derives from `RootController`, I would like the resolved type to be instrumented with AOP logging, per my `ReportAttributePolicy`.

When I execute the above code, none of the methods on my ReportAttributePolicy are executed.  This means I don't have a chance to make magic happen.  If I'm not dealing with an inheritance example, then it all works fine.

How do I make it work with inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `container.Resolve(...)`, Unity looks for a configured interceptor.  If there is none present, no interception is performed.  This check is done **on the type that was requested to be resolved**.  Since you called resolve on `MyController` and that type did not have a configured interceptor, no interception was performed.  The only way around this is to register all of your controllers that derive from `RootController` and set an interceptor.  I have included some helper methods to make this easy...

```
public static IUnityContainer EnableInterception<T>(this IUnityContainer container)
{
    container.EnableInterception(typeof (T));
    return container;
}

public static IUnityContainer EnableInterception(this IUnityContainer container, Type type)
{
    if (type.IsInterface)
        container.Configure<Interception>().SetInterceptorFor(type, new InterfaceInterceptor());
    else
        container.Configure<Interception>().SetInterceptorFor(type, new VirtualMethodInterceptor());
    return container;
}

public static IUnityContainer EnableInterception(this IUnityContainer container, IEnumerable<Type> types)
{
    foreach (var type in types)
    {
        container.EnableInterception(type);
    }
    return container;
}

public static IEnumerable<Type> DerivedFrom<T>(this IEnumerable<Type> types)
{
    return types.Where(t => typeof (T).IsAssignableFrom(t) && typeof (T) != t);
}
```

With these extensions and with the new Unity 3.0 registration by convention methods, the task of registering and enabling interception becomes pretty simple.

```
var controllers = AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies().DerivedFrom<RootController>();

container.RegisterTypes(
    controllers, 
    WithMappings.None, 
    WithName.Default, 
    WithLifetime.Transient);

container.EnableInterception(controllers);
```